# Происхождение слова "дока"

Tags: этимология

Когда хотят подчеркнуть, что человек в чем-то специалист и мастер, говорят: "Он в этом деле дока". Но что это за слово? Оно вообще русское?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Даля:  "ДОКА - мастер, мастак, знаток, искусник,делец.... иногда и знахарь, колдун. ДОКАТОЧНЫЙ - знающий, опытный, деловой, дошлый".

В этимологическом словаре Фасмера :" ***Обычно считают семинарским образованием от лат. doctus, doctor "ученый***"; см. Горяев, ЭС 93; Преобр. 1, 188. Напротив, Зеленин (РФВ 54, 118) объяснял это слово как **исконнорусск., от до́шлый**."